# Different eigenvalues using two different methods

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gaussian-elimination

I have to find the Eigen values of the following matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 &4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I used row operations : **R4->R3-2R4**

and I got : $$
\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -8
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, for a triangular matrix, Eigen values are the diagonal elements. Hence, **E.V = {2,3,-2,-8}**

But we also now that,

$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$**SUM of Eigen values = Trace(Matrix)**

$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$$\>$**PRODUCT of Eigen values = Det(Matrix)**.

But by that logic the above mentioned Eigen values are not satisfied. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you want the eigenvalues of the original matrix or the transformed matrix?

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak It *is* **upper** triangular, as all entries below the diagonal are $0$.

Comment: OK, I agree it is upper triangular matrix.

Comment: @peterwhy Shouldn't both their Eigen values be same?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213716/why-cant-i-row-reduce-and-get-the-same-eigen-values)

Comment: Now you have a counterexample that they are not always the same. Even if you perform row operations on $I$ to obtain $2I$, one matrix satisfies $Iv=1v$ while the other satisfies $(2I)v=2v$, for all vectors $v$.

Comment: @BruceWayne Row operations do not preserve eigenvalues

Comment: Row operations can transform any non singular matrix to the identity matrix, so row operations don't preserve eigenvalues.  Note $R_4 \to (-1/2)R_3+R_4$ changes R_4 to $0,0,0,4$.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the comments, row operations, in general, do not preserve eigenvalues.

The operation $R_4\to R_3- 2R_4 $ which you applied, does not even preserve the determinant... The determinant after this row operation is scaled by a factor of $-2$.

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}2 & \color{red}{-1} & 0 & 0\\
\color{red} 0 & \color{red} 3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \color{blue}{-2} & \color{blue}{0}\\
0 & 0 & \color{blue}{-1} &\color{blue}{4}
\end{bmatrix}$$

You can easily find the eigenvalues of this matrix by observing that it is block diagonal matrix (consisting of two $2\times 2$ blocks along the diagonal).

The red block is upper triangular and has eigenvalues $2$ and $3$.

The blue block is lower triangular and has eigenvalues $-2$ and $4$.

Thus, the eigenvalues of $A$ are $2$, $3$, $-2$, $4$. [See this why.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1308020/955582)